# Spark streaming error: Accumulator must be registered before send to executor

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to do some statistic job. Here is my code:

```
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(60))
val eventHubsStream = EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream(streamingContext, eventHubsParameters)//create a stream

val accum =  sparkSession.sparkContext.longAccumulator("Total Count")

eventHubsStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    accum.add(rdd.count())
    SavetoStorage(accum); //save to storage
})
```

When I run the above program, I got a runtime error:

> "Accumulator must be registered before send to executor"

I have already registered the accumulator here:

```
val accum =  sparkSession.sparkContext.longAccumulator("Total Count")
```

Why do I receive such an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It can be fixed if you register an accumulator. In Spark 2.2 next code works well

```
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.register(accum, <Name_of_your_accumulator>);
    ... next actions with accumulator ...
```

I hope it will not be broken in next releases